# Terminate all open connections using single CLI command on PostgreSQL 12

Tags: bash, postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a CLI command like this:

```sh
$ psql -U postgres < <(psql -U postgres -Atc "select 'SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
    FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = \''||datname||'\'; /* I WILL ADD MORE QUERIES HERE LATER. */
    'from pg_database where 
    datistemplate=false AND datname != 'postgres';")
```

#### Actual Result:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 2: FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = \''||datname||'\';
                                                             ^
```

#### Expected Result:

```sql
WHERE datname = 'database_name'
-- instead of
WHERE datname = \''||datname||'\'
```

This will print and echo to `psql` for each found database instance. However, `datname` is not properly populated. It is because of `'` (Escape?). How can I <s>terminate open connections to the databases other than `postgres` in this CLI command</s> fix this command? Why can't I populate `||datname||` here?

#### Goal:

My goal is to drop all connections if any, to all databases other than `postgres` database. But doing this by in CLI/Bash. Not by logging in to `sudo -u postgres`. I want to drop all connections via CLI-only. I will use this in CI/CD system therefore user interaction is not possible.

Comment: You could always do `$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

Comment: No. In My CI system, I cannot do `systemctl restart`. Also I will do some other tasks after i drop those databases. I do other parts successfully. I am only unable to terminate connections. In PG13, this is introduced as `DROP DATABASE my_db WITH(FORCE)` however some of my applications still depends on PG12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your single quotes don't need to protected from the shell, because they are already inside double quotes.  And to protect them from psql, you double them, not back-whack them.  So

```
psql -U postgres < <(psql -U postgres -Atc "select 'SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
    FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = '''||datname||'''; /* I WILL ADD MORE QUERIES HERE LATER. */
    'from pg_database where 
    datistemplate=false AND datname != 'postgres';")
```

But you could probably use `\gexec` to make this better, by having only one `psql` call rather than two.

Comment: Worked smoothly! Thank you @jjanes